# When and why "угу" replaced "ага"?

Tags: лексикон

I know that nasals are used when pronouncing the interjection, but I always perceived the full form to be "ага". I wonder what and when happened so that people started to write "угу"?

Comment: I think, it's like "when and why Okay replaced OK?" vernacular phrase

Comment: In fact, no difference. but "ага" is more positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I wouldn't say that *угу* replaced *ага*. [According to the corpora](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/ngram.xml?mode=main&t1=%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0&t2=%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83&start=1680&end=2012&smoothing=1), the usage frequency has been growing in parallel, *угу* always being less frequent than *ага*.
2. The meaning of the two words is more or less the same:

   > Большой толковый словарь: УГУ, частица. *Разг.-сниж.* Выражает согласие с чем-л., подтверждение чего-л.; да, так. 
   > — Вы хотите пить? — Угу. 
   > — Надо выйти из вагона. — Угу.
   >
   > Большой толковый словарь: АГА [aha]. частица. *Разг.-сниж.* Употр. для выражения согласия, подтверждения; да, хорошо, так. *Встретились? — Ага.*
3. *Ага* can also have an additional emotional meaning, which *угу* does not have:

   > Большой толковый словарь: *межд.* Выражает злорадство, торжество, замешательство и т.п. *Ага, Мамон! дрожишь передо мною* (Пушкин).

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the two words are partial synonyms. 'Угу' is really pronounced with nasals, 'ага' is not, the vowels are fully articulated, but Г sounds different, it's a velar voiced fricative in 'ага'.

Both words are interjections. 'Угу' expresses agreement, consent, often an unwilling, reserved, or irritated one: *Ты меня понял, Шикалов? ― Угу, ― мрачно кивнул Шикалов.*

'Aга' also expresses agreement, consent, but a neutral one: *— Ага, — согласился Зубов и выпил.*

Also, 'aга' expresses surprise, happiness: *— Ага, тут у вас и лимончик есть!*
or the feeling of revelation, triumph (like English 'Gotcha!'): *Ага, вот ты где!*

Comment: Can you support the idea that these are different words rather than just different spellings of one word  (like че/чего, шо/что)

Comment: Sure, I said it in the first sentence. They are different words. There's one more interjection that sounds similarly, 'эге', expressing surprise or agreement. They are differnt words.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, it's "A-ha" versus "M-hm". Nobody actually says "угу", they just reluctantly say "ага" with they mouth shut.

Comment: good point, "угу" is actually "m-hm"

Comment: With 'Nobody actually says "угу"' you are too general. There are people who frequently say that.

Answer (score 4):

"Ага" гораздо ближе к "да", нежели "угу". "Угу" обычно говорят, когда тема разговора неинтересна и угукают только для того, чтобы хоть что-то сказать.

Answer (score 1):

It is also typical to use 'Ага' to express sudden discovery of hidden link, like 'Bingo!'. Imagine you explore some complex machinery and as you push some buttons in some particular sequence, a hatch opens somewhere, and you suddenly understand why it happened or how it worked. 'Ага..' exclaim you to yourself :) But never 'угу'

Answer (score 1):

Actually here is a good example illustrating the difference between *ага* and *угу*.

> Посетитель ресторана, старый еврей, обращается к официанту, тоже еврею, но молодому:
>   — Мойша, попробуй суп!
>   — Что такое? Это такой же суп, как всегда.
>   — Попробуй!
>   — Да я же никогда не подавал вам плохой суп!
>   — А я тебе говорю: попробуй!
>   — Ну хорошо, хорошо, попробую... А где же ложка?
>   — Ага! — говорит посетитель.

Comment: I don't see how this demonstrate the difference.

Comment: Well it is imposible to use "угу" instead of "ага" in this context. Otherwise the punch line of the joke will be lost.

Comment: Iа "угу" is pronounced as written, it would not be understood. If it is pronounced with nasals, it cannot be pronounced loudly, as in the exclamation just physically. Угу is just the relaxed form of ага.

Answer (score -1):

"Ага" произносят тогда, когда согласны.

"Ага" произносит человек который внимательно слушет и охотно помогает собеседнику.

"Угу" произносят тогда, когда согласны,но сейчас заняты либо не могут открыть рот.

Пример:

> -Дорогой,убери в гараже!
>   -Ага дорогая!

или за завтраком:

> -Дорогой ты будешь мыть посуду?
>   -угу!
>
> -Дорогой,ты починишь кран?
>   -угу,дорогая,но я смотрю футбол!